# A functional equation of the Mellin transform is an equation for the function?

Tags: cv.complex-variables

If the Mellin transform of $f$, $M[f](s)=\int_0^{\infty} t^{s-1}f(t)dt$ can be prolongated in a meromorphic function over the complex numbers and is such that
$$
M[f](s)=M[f](a-s),
$$
then have we
$$
f(t)=\frac{1}{t^a} f\Big(\frac{1}{t}\Big)+\sum_{i=1}^k a_i (t^{b_i}-t^{-b_i-a}),
$$
where $a_i,b_i$ are complex numbers?

Comment: Do you really need these extra terms? The Fourier transform of $f(e^x)e^{ax/2}$ is even, thus this function is even itself.

Comment: For example, if we take $f(t)=\theta_3 (t)-1$, we have extra terms. In this case, the Riemann zeta function appears.